# Call made to adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController even for iPad sim

Tags: ios8, adaptive-ui

I have a viewcontroller implementing the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method of:

```
adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!, traitCollection: UITraitCollection!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
```

As far as I understood, this should be called only for compact size such as iPhone 6, but not for iPad. But in one project, it is called even for iPad, and as a result, I don't get a popover but the full screen modal thing.

I can't see what could be causing this to happen. I looked into another project with roughly the same setup and confirmed that this method doesn't get called during iPad sim (only iphone).

Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 2):

I found out what's wrong. I picked the wrong func during code completion, the correct delegate method I meant to use is:

```
adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
```

not

```
adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!, traitCollection: UITraitCollection!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your iOS level, you should be using `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController: traitCollection:`

I'm using this method (returning `.None`) and it's working on all devices I've tested so far.

In the Apple documentation for `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:` it says this:

> In iOS 8.3 and later, use the adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection: method to handle all trait changes instead of this method. If you do not implement that method, you can use this method to change the presentation style when transitioning to a horizontally compact environment.

**Edit**
For my target iOS of 8, I'm actually using both of these methods.  pre-8.3 won't use the one with `traitCollection:`